# Dupe banner on mobile does not match full site

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, design, dupehammer, user-experience

This is related to my post [It looks like the duplicate banner changed. How does it work now?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307579/it-looks-like-the-duplicate-banner-changed-how-does-it-work-now)

On the full site we now show the gold badge that was used to close the question

[image]

But when we look at the banner on mobile the

[image]

Can the mobile site be updated to have the same UI as the full site so we can see the shiny gold badge?

It also looks like there could be a little spacing added between the name and the badge on mobile as right now it butts right up to the name.

Comment: We'll have a look. Thanks for the report!

Answer (score 8):

You can "Update" to the full version of the site, to see the shiny gold badge.

Just press this button in the site's footer:

[image]

The whole idea of having a mobile version is to reduce assets loaded over crappy connections.
(Although loading a single sprites file is pretty insignificant)

---

In case this wasn't actually a design choice, but a simple oversight, I wouldn't be opposed to some consistency in the *"Mjölnir'd!"* message.

Comment: If the sprites file *is* significant, what about a [bullet](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2022/index.htm) with a gold font color as a compromise?

Comment: That circle looks suspiciously non-freehand, and non-circular.